# Order by Number, Number with Letters, and then Letters PostgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by

Is there a way to have a PostgresQL statement that takes all the data in a particular column and can sort them in the order of Number, Number with Letters, and then Letters? One of my biggest problems is that I also have special characters in the numbers and the alphanumeric values which makes it harder to sort.

Here's is an example of the data that I'm handling

```
EL-300-A
EL-580
J-38125
Nick
Nick1.0
javier
test
test1
test32
test2121AgainOn4/28
test12345
test123467 againOn4/28
test123467
test123467 again
```

Anyone know of the best way to build the Order By statement in PostgresQL?

Comment: Define "number" and "number with letters".

Comment: number being an integer with decimals, and number and letters being a mix of integers and varchars to make a string

Answer (score 0):

Databases do not support this opportunity using the `order by` commands. But, you can do it in other methods. For example:

```
select 
    "name", 
    regexp_replace("name", '[\d]',  '', 'g') as only_letters, 
    regexp_replace("name", '[^\.\d]', '', 'g') as only_numbers 
from examples.term
order by only_letters, only_numbers
```

In this query firstly I extract only letters and only numbers as additional fields. Then use ordering by these fields.

Comment: you don't have to select the values: `order by regexp_replace("name", '[\d]',  '', 'g'), regexp_replace("name", '[^\.\d]', '', 'g')`